# How to do child's clean work in the parent's component

Tags: typescript, angular

I have a `parent` and a `child` component. The `parent` component actually is a page. The `child` component wants to do some clean work related with database.

When I close the `parent` page/component. What I suppose is

`child ngOnDestroy` -> `child cleanWork` -> `parent ngOnDestroy`.

The actual is

`child ngOnDestroy` -> `parent ngOnDestroy`.

**// parent**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'parent',
  template: `
    <child
     (cleanWork)="onCleanWork()">
    </child>
  `
})
export class ParentComponent {
  ngOnDestroy() {
    console.log('parent ngOnDestroy');
  }

  onCleanWork() {
    console.log('child cleanWork');
    // dispatch an action, or do something with database
  }
}
```

**// child**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  template: `Hi`
})
export class ChildComponent {
  @Output() cleanWork = new EventEmitter();

  ngOnDestroy() {
    console.log('child ngOnDestroy');
    this.cleanWork.emit(null);
  }
}
```

The reason I am doing the clean work inside of the child is because I want the child be **dumb**. Is there any alternative/better way? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got help from Brandt B. @babeal on Gitter.

Since I am using ngrx/store, I should put all database related actions in the parent smart component, instead of `emit` in child component first, then do an action in the parent.

In this case, I should do the clean work in parent component directly.

[Presentational and Container Components](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0#.yomo20qqf) will help understand.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a reference to a `child` from `parent`:

```
@ViewChild(ChildComponent) child: ChildComponent;
```

And then call clean up routing from `parent` when it's needed (your `ngOnDestroy`)

```
ngOnDestroy() {
  child.cleanup();
}
```

Comment: thanks, but for this way, the database related codes are still in child component, right?